# Installed application cache file name 

Tags: android

can we track installed application cache file name and location.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With any `android.context.Content` object such as inside an Activity you can get the path name of the cache directory with a call to `getCacheDir()`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()

Comment: Thanks Jim. Can we also get the list of files these are presented in cache dir?

Comment: Sure, off the top of my head, make a File object to represent the directory (from the path returned by getCacheDir()) then use listFiles http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#listFiles()

Comment: perfect jim . I was thinking the same just confirming from you.

Comment: Glad to help. Best of luck with your app.